# SVG linear gradient displayed differently by different software when x2 attribute is not present

Tags: browser, inkscape, svg, standards

I’ve recently imported and edited a file in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).
I saved the image as “optimized SVG” in Inkscape, but when I opened the resulting file in different programs, some displayed it the same as Inkscape, while others weren’t applying a particular linear gradient (while all the other parts of the image, including gradients, were working fine).

So far for the backstory.
I’ve condensed my original image into a minimal example and determined which part of the SVG source makes different viewers behave differently.
This is my example SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="982" width="982" version="1.1"
 viewBox="0 0 982 982">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(-62.075 1070.8 1070.8 62.075 521.8 -42.09)">
   <stop stop-color="#bbb9c2" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#3f3" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <path fill="url(#a)" d="m0 491.11c0 271.12 219.78 490.89 490.85 490.89 271.13 0 490.92-219.77 490.92-490.89 0-271.07-219.79-490.86-490.92-490.86-271.07 0-490.85 219.79-490.85 490.86"/>
</svg>
```

This is what it looks like in Inkscape and the [GNOME image viewer (“Eye of GNOME”)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome):
[image: example SVG image in Inkscape or Eye of GNOME]

This is what it looks like in the Firefox and Chromium web browsers:
[image: example SVG image in Firefox or Chromium]

However, I noticed that **if you add the attribute `x2="1"` to the `<linearGradient>` element, the image looks the same in all these viewers**.

Unfortunately, I’m not familiar enough with the details of the SVG file format and the [SVG standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/), but it seems clear to me that **one of these interpretations of my file must be wrong (i.e. violates the standard)**.
Does anyone know whose side is right (i.e. which programs should I file a bug report for)?

Comment: The standard [quite clearly states](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementX1Attribute) that all of x1, x2, y1, and y2 are optional and have default values.

Comment: And there seems to be a bug in the standard, since the defaults are, respectively, 0%, 100%, 0%, and **0%**.

Comment: @Juancho Aaah, I see. I wouldn’t have expected that, but if you think about it, it makes sense. A gradient vector that is the null vector doesn’t really make sense, so they can’t set all defaults to 0%, and arbitrarily picked a vector pointing in the positive x direction. So I don’t think it’s a bug in the standard, but in the software that doesn’t implement these defaults correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I’m not entirely sure yet which of the two representations is correct, but I suspect it is the one displayed by the web browsers because I have discovered bugs affecting the behavior in my example in both Inkscape and Eye of GNOME (see below).

I *have* figured out the reason for how I was made aware of this issue in the first place: The SVG file I had opened with Inkscape had a `<linearGradient>` with the attributes `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` and `x2="1"` (just like in my example). When saving as “optimized SVG”, Inkscape “optimized away” the `x2="1"` attribute because it interpreted this as equivalent to `x2="100%"`, which is the default for the `x2` attribute [as specified by the SVG standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#LinearGradientElementX1Attribute) and thus could be omitted. *However*, Inkscape’s interpretation of `x2="100%"` ⇔ `x2="1"` is (probably) incorrect – this is [Inkscape bug #1153706](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1153706).

In my research on this issue, I have encountered various inconsistencies about how different software handles `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` in combination with the gradient vector attributes `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`. The following are bug reports that either already existed or which I haved filed myself as a result of my findings:

- Inkscape – [bug #1153706: “gradientUnits userSpaceOnUse using wrong viewport”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1153706)
- scour – [bug #66: “Gradient on clipping path lost when optimizing with scour”](https://github.com/scour-project/scour/issues/66)
- librsvg (used by GNOME software such as Eye of GNOME or GIMP) – [bug #778187: “SVG: property x2 on gradients handled incorrectly with gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"”](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778187)
- ImageMagick – [“gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" rendered incorrectly”](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31338) (it seems like ImageMagick doesn’t even have a real bug tracker…)